# Dynamics on surfaces in Blender render as in Unreal engine

Tags: animation, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, compositing-nodes

How to set dynamics on the surface with some texure ?
1) How control the glare on this surface? (*but not overall scene*). *If I set glare  node in compositor it affects whole scene.*

2) How to set this moving/dynamics with  distortion noise/musgrave/magic texture ?

I want  to create this similar effect:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-BLfThM3JE

[image: Mass effect 3]

[image: ME3 particle effect]
[image: ME3_3]

On this images are involved particle effects also. I know how to make it, I just need this dynamics on sphere. This transparent sphere  is not static, it scales to some value and some distortion noise is moving along them.

What I've made:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13451287/masseffectsurface.blend
[image: Blender surface]